# passwd command - not working properly

Tags: command-line, passwd

After adding my Ubuntu 20.4.1 to the domain and enabling the login from adsys and pam package, the `passwd` command gives that the password was changed successfully without prompting to enter a new password.

Command Output:

```
imad@escwa-localrepo:~$ passwd
passwd: password updated successfully
```

Comment: I would check your release details.... Ubuntu release are *year.month* in format, so 20.04 refers to the 2020-April release, and an updated system will be 20.04.5 not 20.04.1, meaning you're well behind on security fixes & patches; or your provided details were incorrect. If still using 20.04.1 you're indicating no application of security & package updates since before February 2021  ([this](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/) shows the ISO release date but installed systems upgraded awhile before that date!)